# How to replace None only with empty string using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

the code below generates a *df*:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

dates = [dt(2014, 1, 2, 2), dt(2014, 1, 2, 3), dt(2014, 1, 2, 4), None]
strings1 = ['A', 'B',None, 'C']
strings2 = [None, 'B','C', 'C']
strings3 = ['A', 'B','C', None]
vals = [1.,2.,np.nan, 4.]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(['A','B','C','D','E'],
                           [strings1, dates, strings2, strings3, vals])))



+---+------+---------------------+------+------+-----+
|   |  A   |          B          |  C   |  D   |  E  |
+---+------+---------------------+------+------+-----+
| 0 | A    | 2014-01-02 02:00:00 | None | A    | 1   |
| 1 | B    | 2014-01-02 03:00:00 | B    | B    | 2   |
| 2 | None | 2014-01-02 04:00:00 | C    | C    | NaN |
| 3 | C    | NaT                 | C    | None | 4   |
+---+------+---------------------+------+------+-----+
```

I would like to replace all `None` (real `None` in python, not str) inside with `''`(empty string).

The **expected** *df* is

```
+---+---+---------------------+---+---+-----+
|   | A |          B          | C | D |  E  |
+---+---+---------------------+---+---+-----+
| 0 | A | 2014-01-02 02:00:00 |   | A | 1   |
| 1 | B | 2014-01-02 03:00:00 | B | B | 2   |
| 2 |   | 2014-01-02 04:00:00 | C | C | NaN |
| 3 | C | NaT                 | C |   | 4   |
+---+---+---------------------+---+---+-----+
```

---

what I did is

`df = df.replace([None], [''], regex=True)`

But I got

```
+---+---+---------------------+---+------+---+
|   | A |          B          | C |  D   | E |
+---+---+---------------------+---+------+---+
| 0 | A | 1388628000000000000 |   | A    | 1 |
| 1 | B | 1388631600000000000 | B | B    | 2 |
| 2 |   | 1388635200000000000 | C | C    |   |
| 3 | C |                     | C |      | 4 |
+---+---+---------------------+---+------+---+
```

---

1. all the dates becomes big numbers
2. Even `NaT` and `NaN` are replaced, which I don't want.

How can I achieve that correctly and efficently?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like `None` is being promoted to `NaN` and so you cannot use `replace` like usual, the following works:

```
In [126]:
mask = df.applymap(lambda x: x is None)
cols = df.columns[(mask).any()]
for col in df[cols]:
    df.loc[mask[col], col] = ''
df

Out[126]:
   A                   B  C  D   E
0  A 2014-01-02 02:00:00     A   1
1  B 2014-01-02 03:00:00  B  B   2
2    2014-01-02 04:00:00  C  C NaN
3  C                 NaT  C      4
```

So we generate a mask of the `None` values using `applymap`, we then use this mask to iterate over each column of interest and using the boolean mask set the values.

Answer (score 38):

This is sufficient

```
df.fillna("",inplace=True)
```

```py
df
Out[142]: 
   A                    B  C  D  E
0  A  2014-01-02 02:00:00     A  1
1  B  2014-01-02 03:00:00  B  B  2
2     2014-01-02 04:00:00  C  C   
3  C                       C     4
```

**edit 2021-07-26** complete response following @dWitty's comment

If you really want to keep Nat and NaN values on other than text, you just need fill Na for your text column
In your exemple this is A, C, D

You just send a dict of replacement **value** for your columns. value can be differents for each column. For your case you just need construct the dict

```
# default values to replace NA (None)
# values = {"A": "", "C": "", "D": ""}
values = (dict([[e,""] for e in ['A','C','D']]))
df.fillna(value=values, inplace=True)
```

```
df
Out[142]: 
   A                   B  C  D    E
0  A 2014-01-02 02:00:00     A  1.0
1  B 2014-01-02 03:00:00  B  B  2.0
2    2014-01-02 04:00:00  C  C  NaN
3  C                 NaT  C     4.0
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: the question explicitly asks about replacing None _only_, not also any NaN

Answer (score 6):

Since the relevant columns you wish to alter are all objects, you could just specify this with the dtype attribute (for completeness I added in string and unicode) and use [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

So:

```
for c in df:
   if str(df[c].dtype) in ('object', 'string_', 'unicode_'):
        df[c].fillna(value='', inplace=True)
```

This will leave numeric and date columns unaffected.

To see the data types for all columns:

```
df.dtypes
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use replace method. It works properly.

```
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/drop-rows-containing-empty-cells-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

For those who are trying to replace `None`, and not just `np.nan` (which is covered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63297969/913098))

```
default_value = ""
df.apply(lambda x: x if x is not None else default_value)
```

here is a nice one-liner