# Comparison on None works element-wise but not in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to see if any values change in my dataframe, from row to row.  One column in particular has a lot of `None` values.
If I check for inequality between `None` values, *element-wise*, it gives the answer I expect (that is, `None != None` returns `False`), but not when I do that same comparison on the column.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
>>> example_data = [None]*3 + ['a','b','b'] + [None]*4
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(example_data, columns = ['col1'])
>>> print df

    col1
0   None
1   None
2   None
3   a
4   b
5   b
6   None
7   None
8   None
9   None
```

To see if the value changed from one line to the next, I'm shifting everything and comparing the values:

```
>>> did_it_change = (df != df.shift(1))
>>> print did_it_change

    col1
0   True
1   True
2   True
3   True
4   True
5   False
6   True
7   True
8   True
9   True
```

So long as `None` is not involved in the comparison, it's accurate (e.g. row 5 changed the value to `b` from its previous value of `b`, so it did not change).

If I check a single element, it works as expected:

```
>>> df.loc[1,'col1'] != df.loc[2,'col1']
False
```

But that's not the answer that appears in the full column: `did_it_change.loc[1,:]` is `True`.

I do get the expected outcome if I use `""` instead of `None`, but replacing `None` with empty string [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295740/how-to-replace-none-only-with-empty-string-using-pandas) seems arbitrary and superfluous.

This is the outcome I'd expect.

```
>>> example_data = [""]*3 + ['a','b','b'] + [""]*4
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(example_data, columns = ['col1']) 
>>> did_it_change = (df != df.shift(1))
>>> print did_it_change

    col1
0   True
1   False
2   False
3   True
4   True
5   False
6   True
7   False
8   False
9   False
```

What's going on here?  Why does the comparison with `None` give different answers if I'm calling it on a dataframe column instead of its elements?

Comment: I suspect that `None` is getting converted to `np.nan` underneath the hood when doing DataFrame level operations, which would explain the output as `np.nan != np.nan` returns `True` by definition.  See the output of `df == df`.

Comment: Good theory!  I just ran `df == df` and sure enough, the `None` values are not equal to themselves.  At least now I know why it's happening.  I still think this is undesired behavior...