# How to handle non-numeric entries in an integer valued column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` and one of the columns `count` is contains strings. These strings are mostly convertable to integers (e.g. `0006`) which is what I will do with them. However some of the entries in `count` are blank strings of spaces. How can I

- Drop all the rows where the `count` value is a blank string.
- Substitute all the blank values in that column with some numeric value of my choice.

The dataframe is very large if there are particularly efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas DataFrame remove Empty Cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/python-pandas-dataframe-remove-empty-cells)

Comment: So you want to do two incompatible things, right? Once you have dropped blank values then there is no point substituting blank values...

Comment: Yes those were meant to be two different options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dropna` or `fillna` after `pd.to_numeric(errosr='coerce')`

consider a pandas series `s`

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(('0001', ''), 1000000), name='intish')
```

***drop method 1*** (less robust)

```
s[s != ''].astype(int)
```

***drop method 2*** (more robust)

```
pd.to_numeric(s, 'coerce').dropna().astype(int)
```

***drop timing***

[image]

*More robust method is faster*

---

***fill method 1***

```
pd.to_numeric(s, 'coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

***fill method 2***

```
s.where(s.astype(bool), 0).astype(int)
```

***fill timing***

[image]

*Takes same amount of time as dropping*

Comment: Technically you should also cast to `int` in the fill case :)

Comment: Thanks. One detail is that my blank strings are not empty. I need to use .strip I think as they are a variable number of spaces.

Comment: `s.str.strip()` should do that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want two different things. But first, convert column [to numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric) and coerce errors:

```
df['count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['count'], errors='coerce')
```

To drop rows (use `subset` to avoid dropping `NaN` from other columns):

```
df.dropna(subset=['count'])
```

To replace with default value:

```
df['count'] = df['count'].fillna(default_value)
```