# pandas: remove rows with missing data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using the following code to remove some rows with missing data in pandas:

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True)
df = df.replace(r'^\t+$', np.nan, regex=True)
df = df.dropna()
```

However, I still have some cells in the data frame looks blank/empty. Why is this happening? Any way to get rid of rows with such empty/blank cells? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us samples of the dataframe so that we can reproduce the problems

Comment: What about `df = df.replace('', np.nan)` ?

Comment: Like @jezrael said, try adding `df = df.replace('', np.nan, regex=True)` before `dropna` in your code

Comment: @jezrael: add df = df.replace('', np.nan) works. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas DataFrame remove Empty Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/python-pandas-dataframe-remove-empty-cells)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```

If want simplify your code is possible join regexes by `|` and for empty space use `^$`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':['',5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':['','  ','   ',4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,'       ',0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

df = df.replace(r'^\s+$|^\t+$|^$', np.nan, regex=True)
print (df)
   A    B    C    D  E  F
0  a  NaN  NaN  1.0  5  a
1  b  5.0  NaN  3.0  3  a
2  c  4.0  NaN  5.0  6  a
3  d  5.0  4.0  7.0  9  b
4  e  5.0  2.0  NaN  2  b
5  f  4.0  3.0  0.0  4  b
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of pandas you may do:

> DataFrame.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None,
>   inplace=False) axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
>
> Determine if rows or columns which contain missing values are removed.
>
> 0, or ‘index’ : Drop rows which contain missing values.
>    1, or ‘columns’ : Drop columns which contain missing value.
>
> ```
> Deprecated since version 0.23.0:: Pass tuple or list to drop on multiple
> ```
>
> axes. [source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

So, for now to drop rows with empty values

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0)
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing code with input and output data:

**Input:**

```
Original DataFrame:
Name   Age         City
0  Alice  25.0     New York
1    Bob   NaN  Los Angeles
2    NaN  30.0     New York
3  Diana  22.0          NaN
4  Ethan   NaN      Chicago
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', np.nan, 'Diana', 'Ethan'],
    'Age': [25, np.nan, 30, 22, np.nan],
    'City': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'New York', np.nan, 'Chicago']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)
"""
    Here Im dropping null value of specific column
"""
df_cleaned = df.dropna(subset=['Name', 'Age', 'City'])
print("DataFrame after removing rows with missing data:")
print(df_cleaned)
```

**Output:**

```
DataFrame after removing rows with missing data:
Name   Age      City
0  Alice  25.0  New York
```