# How to drop a row where half of information is missing pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some data I want to delete the some rows but where half of information is missing.

```
Employee_name
employee: ahmad
employee: ali
employee:
employee: abc
employee:
```

I want to delete all employee record whos name is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.Employee_name.str.strip().str.strip('employee:').ne('')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```

as suggested by *jezrael* in [Pandas: remove rows with missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960348/pandas-remove-rows-with-missing-data)

Answer (score 0):

Another way
Data

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Employee_name':
['employee: ahmad',
'employee: ali',
'employee:',
'employee: abc',
'employee:'] })
df
```

Extract strings after : and drop NaN

```
df['Employee']=df['Employee_name'].str.extract(r'(?<=\:)(\s+[a-z]+)')
df.dropna()
```

Regex explanation
`(?<=X)(Y)` Get Y if X precedes it
  `X` is `:`
  `Y` is either `space` `\s` followed by  `small alphabets` `[a-z]+` text or space

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There multiple ways to achieve that, you may do this through the command below as per suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

```
data = data[data.employee != '']
```

Another approach is as per below:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.DataFrame( {'employee' :  ['Ali', '', 'Amed', '', '', 'abc']}, columns = ['employee'])
delRows = data[ data['employee'] == '' ].index
data.drop(delRows , inplace=True)
data
```

The Output is:

```
    employee
0   Ali
2   Amed
5   abc
```