# How to to predict the model using linear regression?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to predict the housing price for this  [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xNs7f_HC64Pvfe_M9Ai-f5NQUr3t-N6y/view?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to use Linear regression model, I'm getting value error as 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: as shown below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
data = pd.read_csv("Predicting-House-Prices-In-Bengaluru-Train-Data.csv")
data.head()

area_type   availability    location    size    society total_sqft  bath    balcony price
0   Super built-up Area 19-Dec  Electronic City Phase II    2 BHK   Coomee  1056    2.0 1.0 39.07
1   Plot Area   Ready To Move   Chikka Tirupathi    4 Bedroom   Theanmp 2600    5.0 3.0 120.00
2   Built-up Area   Ready To Move   Uttarahalli 3 BHK   NaN 1440    2.0 3.0 62.00
3   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Lingadheeranahalli  3 BHK   Soiewre 1521    3.0 1.0 95.00
4   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Kothanur    2 BHK   NaN 1200    2.0 1.0 51.00
data['location'].fillna('', inplace=True)
data.drop([47],axis=0)
    area_type   availability    location    size    society total_sqft  bath    balcony price
0   Super built-up Area 19-Dec  Electronic City Phase II    2 BHK   Coomee  1056    2.0 1.0 39.07
1   Plot Area   Ready To Move   Chikka Tirupathi    4 Bedroom   Theanmp 2600    5.0 3.0 120.00
2   Built-up Area   Ready To Move   Uttarahalli 3 BHK   NaN 1440    2.0 3.0 62.00
3   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Lingadheeranahalli  3 BHK   Soiewre 1521    3.0 1.0 95.00
4   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Kothanur    2 BHK   NaN 1200    2.0 1.0 51.00
5   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Whitefield  2 BHK   DuenaTa 1170    2.0 1.0 38.00
6   Super built-up Area 18-May  Old Airport Road    4 BHK   Jaades  2732    4.0 NaN 204.00
7   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Rajaji Nagar    4 BHK   Brway G 3300    4.0 NaN 600.00
8   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Marathahalli    3 BHK   NaN 1310    3.0 1.0 63.25
9   Plot Area   Ready To Move   Gandhi Bazar    6 Bedroom   NaN 1020    6.0 NaN 370.00
10  Super built-up Area 18-Feb  Whitefield  3 BHK   NaN 1800    2.0 2.0 70.00
11  Plot Area   Ready To Move   Whitefield  4 Bedroom   Prrry M 2785    5.0 3.0 295.00
12  Super built-up Area Ready To Move   7th Phase JP Nagar  2 BHK   Shncyes 1000    2.0 1.0 38.00
13  Built-up Area   Ready To Move   Gottigere   2 BHK   NaN 1100    2.0 2.0 40.00
14  Plot Area   Ready To Move   Sarjapur    3 Bedroom   Skityer 2250    3.0 2.0 148.00
15  Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Mysore Road 2 BHK   PrntaEn 1175    2.0 2.0 73.50
16  Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Bisuvanahalli   3 BHK   Prityel 1180    3.0 2.0 48.00
17  Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Raja Rajeshwari Nagar   3 BHK   GrrvaGr 1540    3.0 3.0 60.00
18  Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Ramakrishnappa Layout   3 BHK   PeBayle 2770    4.0 2.0 290.00
19  Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Manayata Tech Park  2 BHK   NaN 1100    2.0 2.0 48.00
20  Built-up Area   Ready To Move   Kengeri 1 BHK   NaN 600 1.0 1.0 15.00
21  Super built-up Area 19-Dec  Binny Pete  3 BHK   She 2rk 1755    3.0 1.0 122.00
22  Plot Area   Ready To Move   Thanisandra 4 Bedroom   Soitya  2800    5.0 2.0 380.00
23  Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Bellandur   3 BHK   NaN 1767    3.0 1.0 103.00
24  Super built-up Area 18-Nov  Thanisandra 1 RK    Bhe 2ko 510 1.0 0.0 25.25
25  Super built-up Area 18-May  Mangammanapalya 3 BHK   NaN 1250    3.0 2.0 56.00
26  Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Electronic City 2 BHK   Itelaa  660 1.0 1.0 23.10
27  Built-up Area   20-Dec  Whitefield  3 BHK   NaN 1610    3.0 2.0 81.00
28  Super built-up Area 17-Oct  Ramagondanahalli    2 BHK   ViistLa 1151    2.0 2.0 48.77
29  Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Electronic City 3 BHK   KBityo  1025    2.0 1.0 47.00
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
13289   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Sarjapur Road   4 BHK   Maana E 4050    2.0 1.0 450.00
13290   Plot Area   18-Jan  Weavers Colony  1 Bedroom   NaN 812 1.0 0.0 26.00
13291   Super built-up Area 18-Jul  Udayapur Village    3 BHK   Plowsri 1440    2.0 2.0 63.93
13292   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Sarjapur Road   4 BHK   Puallhi 2425    5.0 1.0 195.00
13293   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Sultan Palaya   4 BHK   RSntsAp 2200    3.0 3.0 80.00
13294   Super built-up Area 18-Feb  Haralur Road    3 BHK   SNnia E 1810    3.0 2.0 112.00
13295   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Cox Town    2 BHK   NaN 1200    2.0 2.0 140.00
13296   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Electronic City 2 BHK   GMown E 1060    2.0 1.0 52.00
13297   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Kenchenahalli   2 BHK   AriosPa 1015    2.0 2.0 60.00
13298   Super built-up Area 18-Dec  Whitefield  4 BHK   Prtates 2830 - 2882 5.0 0.0 154.50
13299   Plot Area   Ready To Move   Hosakerehalli   5 Bedroom   NaN 1500    6.0 2.0 145.00
13300   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Kothanur    3 BHK   NaN 1454    3.0 3.0 71.50
13301   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Annaiah Reddy Layout    2 BHK   NaN 1075    2.0 2.0 48.00
13302   Plot Area   Ready To Move   Vidyaranyapura  5 Bedroom   NaN 774 5.0 3.0 70.00
13303   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Raja Rajeshwari Nagar   2 BHK   GrrvaGr 1187    2.0 2.0 40.14
13304   Carpet Area Ready To Move   Hulimavu    1 BHK   NaN 500 1.0 3.0 220.00
13305   Plot Area   Ready To Move   Rajarajeshwari Nagara   4 Bedroom   NaN 1200    5.0 NaN 325.00
13306   Built-up Area   Ready To Move   Billekahalli    3 BHK   NaN 1805    3.0 3.0 134.00
13307   Built-up Area   Ready To Move   Bannerghatta Road   3 BHK   Baanise 1527    3.0 1.0 142.00
13308   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Yeshwanthpur    3 BHK   IBityin 1675    3.0 NaN 92.13
13309   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Rachenahalli    2 BHK   NaN 1050    2.0 2.0 52.71
13310   Plot Area   Ready To Move   Ramamurthy Nagar    7 Bedroom   NaN 1500    9.0 2.0 250.00
13311   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Bellandur   2 BHK   NaN 1262    2.0 2.0 47.00
13312   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Uttarahalli 3 BHK   Aklia R 1345    2.0 1.0 57.00
13313   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Green Glen Layout   3 BHK   SoosePr 1715    3.0 3.0 112.00
13314   Built-up Area   Ready To Move   Whitefield  5 Bedroom   ArsiaEx 3453    4.0 0.0 231.00
13315   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Richards Town   4 BHK   NaN 3600    5.0 NaN 400.00
13316   Built-up Area   Ready To Move   Raja Rajeshwari Nagar   2 BHK   Mahla T 1141    2.0 1.0 60.00
13317   Super built-up Area 18-Jun  Padmanabhanagar 4 BHK   SollyCl 4689    4.0 1.0 488.00
13318   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Doddathoguru    1 BHK   NaN 550 1.0 1.0 17.00
13318 rows × 9 columns
data.head()
    area_type   availability    location    size    society total_sqft  bath    balcony price
0   Super built-up Area 19-Dec  Electronic City Phase II    2 BHK   Coomee  1056    2.0 1.0 39.07
1   Plot Area   Ready To Move   Chikka Tirupathi    4 Bedroom   Theanmp 2600    5.0 3.0 120.00
2   Built-up Area   Ready To Move   Uttarahalli 3 BHK   NaN 1440    2.0 3.0 62.00
3   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Lingadheeranahalli  3 BHK   Soiewre 1521    3.0 1.0 95.00
4   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   Kothanur    2 BHK   NaN 1200    2.0 1.0 51.00
data['location'].isnull().sum()
0
data['total_sqft'].isnull().sum()
0
data['location'].fillna('', inplace=True)
data['location'] = data['location'].astype(str)
data.dtypes
area_type        object
availability     object
location         object
size             object
society          object
total_sqft       object
bath            float64
balcony         float64
price           float64
dtype: object
enc = LabelEncoder()
data.iloc[:,2] = enc.fit_transform(data.iloc[:,2])
data.head()
area_type   availability    location    size    society total_sqft  bath    balcony price
0   Super built-up Area 19-Dec  420 2 BHK   Coomee  1056    2.0 1.0 39.07
1   Plot Area   Ready To Move   318 4 Bedroom   Theanmp 2600    5.0 3.0 120.00
2   Built-up Area   Ready To Move   1180    3 BHK   NaN 1440    2.0 3.0 62.00
3   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   758 3 BHK   Soiewre 1521    3.0 1.0 95.00
4   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   717 2 BHK   NaN 1200    2.0 1.0 51.00
X = data.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
X.head()
area_type   availability    location    size    society total_sqft  bath    balcony
0   Super built-up Area 19-Dec  420 2 BHK   Coomee  1056    2.0 1.0
1   Plot Area   Ready To Move   318 4 Bedroom   Theanmp 2600    5.0 3.0
2   Built-up Area   Ready To Move   1180    3 BHK   NaN 1440    2.0 3.0
3   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   758 3 BHK   Soiewre 1521    3.0 1.0
4   Super built-up Area Ready To Move   717 2 BHK   NaN 1200    2.0 1.0
y = data.price
y.head()
0     39.07
1    120.00
2     62.00
3     95.00
4     51.00
Name: price, dtype: float64
y
0         39.07
1        120.00
2         62.00
3         95.00
4         51.00
5         38.00
6        204.00
7        600.00
8         63.25
9        370.00
10        70.00
11       295.00
12        38.00
13        40.00
14       148.00
15        73.50
16        48.00
17        60.00
18       290.00
19        48.00
20        15.00
21       122.00
22       380.00
23       103.00
24        25.25
25        56.00
26        23.10
27        81.00
28        48.77
29        47.00
          ...  
13289    450.00
13290     26.00
13291     63.93
13292    195.00
13293     80.00
13294    112.00
13295    140.00
13296     52.00
13297     60.00
13298    154.50
13299    145.00
13300     71.50
13301     48.00
13302     70.00
13303     40.14
13304    220.00
13305    325.00
13306    134.00
13307    142.00
13308     92.13
13309     52.71
13310    250.00
13311     47.00
13312     57.00
13313    112.00
13314    231.00
13315    400.00
13316     60.00
13317    488.00
13318     17.00
Name: price, Length: 13319, dtype: float64
X = pd.get_dummies(X, drop_first=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=.3)
X_train
    location    bath    balcony area_type_Carpet Area   area_type_Plot Area area_type_Super built-up Area   availability_14-Nov availability_15-Aug availability_15-Dec availability_15-Jun ... total_sqft_990  total_sqft_991  total_sqft_992  total_sqft_993  total_sqft_994  total_sqft_995  total_sqft_996  total_sqft_997  total_sqft_998  total_sqft_999
9114    665 2.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1324    418 4.0 0.0 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4864    420 2.0 1.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11954   627 3.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11832   1191    2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5065    1000    2.0 1.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12548   1225    2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9745    495 4.0 3.0 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8851    973 2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6012    418 4.0 3.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1956    708 2.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6861    389 5.0 2.0 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7343    642 2.0 2.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8963    638 5.0 1.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3634    418 2.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3300    1057    2.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11290   1169    2.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8659    1139    3.0 0.0 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9313    1154    6.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9993    800 3.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4515    955 3.0 NaN 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2123    1191    2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1189    1191    2.0 2.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4753    140 3.0 NaN 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8321    814 2.0 0.0 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8268    516 2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6184    585 3.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8542    543 2.0 3.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4812    1253    3.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12648   708 2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
3147    537 2.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6309    1193    2.0 1.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2388    75  2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10066   714 4.0 0.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11099   1253    6.0 NaN 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6000    746 3.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11849   1166    2.0 2.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4763    1253    2.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6444    116 2.0 1.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4279    687 2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1842    1011    2.0 3.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2493    689 2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7668    746 2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1599    418 2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
692 157 3.0 3.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9144    307 4.0 1.0 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13190   366 2.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6300    671 3.0 2.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4332    1253    2.0 3.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7061    849 2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2566    1253    2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
876 143 2.0 NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7805    1154    4.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11385   1218    2.0 2.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3363    1253    1.0 0.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9366    893 2.0 1.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4579    269 2.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9362    189 1.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1070    221 2.0 2.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9413    536 2.0 1.0 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9323 rows × 4917 columns
X_train.dtypes
location                            int64
bath                              float64
balcony                           float64
area_type_Carpet  Area              uint8
area_type_Plot  Area                uint8
area_type_Super built-up  Area      uint8
availability_14-Nov                 uint8
availability_15-Aug                 uint8
availability_15-Dec                 uint8
availability_15-Jun                 uint8
availability_15-Nov                 uint8
availability_15-Oct                 uint8
availability_16-Dec                 uint8
availability_16-Jan                 uint8
availability_16-Jul                 uint8
availability_16-Mar                 uint8
availability_16-Nov                 uint8
availability_16-Oct                 uint8
availability_16-Sep                 uint8
availability_17-Apr                 uint8
availability_17-Aug                 uint8
availability_17-Dec                 uint8
availability_17-Feb                 uint8
availability_17-Jan                 uint8
availability_17-Jul                 uint8
availability_17-Jun                 uint8
availability_17-Mar                 uint8
availability_17-May                 uint8
availability_17-Nov                 uint8
availability_17-Oct                 uint8
                                   ...   
total_sqft_967                      uint8
total_sqft_970                      uint8
total_sqft_971                      uint8
total_sqft_972                      uint8
total_sqft_973                      uint8
total_sqft_975                      uint8
total_sqft_976                      uint8
total_sqft_977                      uint8
total_sqft_978                      uint8
total_sqft_980                      uint8
total_sqft_980 - 1030               uint8
total_sqft_981                      uint8
total_sqft_981 - 1249               uint8
total_sqft_982                      uint8
total_sqft_983                      uint8
total_sqft_984                      uint8
total_sqft_985                      uint8
total_sqft_986                      uint8
total_sqft_987                      uint8
total_sqft_989                      uint8
total_sqft_990                      uint8
total_sqft_991                      uint8
total_sqft_992                      uint8
total_sqft_993                      uint8
total_sqft_994                      uint8
total_sqft_995                      uint8
total_sqft_996                      uint8
total_sqft_997                      uint8
total_sqft_998                      uint8
total_sqft_999                      uint8
Length: 4917, dtype: object
y_train
9114      35.00
1324     120.00
4864      37.83
11954     97.00
11832     54.00
5065      48.50
12548     71.95
9745     300.00
8851      45.00
6012     119.00
1956      53.33
6861     145.00
7343      45.00
8963     120.00
3634      68.00
3300      53.00
11290     67.00
8659      66.00
9313     245.00
9993      85.00
4515     700.00
2123      40.00
1189      42.00
4753     150.00
8321     175.00
8268      72.00
6184     168.00
8542      31.50
4812     140.00
12648     50.66
          ...  
3147      86.12
6309      64.00
2388      43.50
10066    625.00
11099    700.00
6000     150.00
11849     59.80
4763      84.00
6444      48.00
4279      58.00
1842      50.00
2493      40.60
7668      75.00
1599      37.50
692      120.00
9144      89.45
13190     69.76
6300      92.00
4332      67.00
7061      63.00
2566      49.50
876       95.00
7805     152.00
11385     89.50
3363      32.79
9366      59.00
4579      42.00
9362      38.77
1070      70.00
9413      69.25
Name: price, Length: 9323, dtype: float64
linear = LinearRegression()
linear.fit(X_train, y_train)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-3975a5a27c36> in <module>()
      1 linear = LinearRegression()
----> 2 linear.fit(X_train, y_train)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    480         n_jobs_ = self.n_jobs
    481         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'],
--> 482                          y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
    483 
    484         if sample_weight is not None and np.atleast_1d(sample_weight).ndim > 1:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    571     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
    572                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
--> 573                     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    574     if multi_output:
    575         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    446         # make sure we actually converted to numeric:
    447         if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind == "O":
--> 448             array = array.astype(np.float64)
    449         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    450             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

So , How can I fix this ValueError where am I getting this error ? inorder to predict the trained data using LinearRegression() ?

Comment: There is _way too much_ code in this question. The error looks like you have empty strings which you'll need to `drop` from the dataset before trying to run the model

Comment: Sorry for the long code. I just wanted to explain every step clearly. How can I find out all empty values?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/python-pandas-dataframe-remove-empty-cells)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have NaN values in your x (x_train and/or x_test). You should fill them with a value or drop row. They are many ways to do and this is one:
`nans = isnan(x)
a[nans] = 0`

or in pandas dataframe : `df.fillna(0)`
also you can drop all rows with `nan` values in pandas:
`df.dropna()`

or in numpy : 
`array[~np.isnan(array).any(axis=1)]`

Comment: if your samples with `nan` are a few, try to drop. (esay  way). But if you want, you can use more statical ways like `average`,`mean` and other.

Comment: I removed a NaN wherever it's present and tested with linear regression model I get precision in -ve value linear = LinearRegression()
linear.fit(X_train, y_train)LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)pred = linear.predict(X_test)r2_score(y_test,pred)-2.7112263389263556e+16 which is not good

Comment: Try to normalize your data. Be aware you should not normalize onehotencoded(categorical values).