# Removing an empty row from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using [this dataset](https://labs.semanticscholar.org/corpus/) and reading it through pandas dataframe. I need to work with the `paperAbsrtract` column only which has some missing data.

```
filename = "sample-S2-records"
df = pd.read_json(filename, lines=True) 
abstract = df['paperAbstract']
```

Because there are some missing data in the `abstract` dataframe, I want to remove those rows that are empty. So following the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), I do below

```
abstract.dropna(how='all')
```

But this doesn't remove those empty rows. They are still there in the `abstract` dataframe. What am I missing?

Comment: We’ll dropna will only recognize values pandas considers null. If by empty you mean the empty string, that doesn’t count. Can you show some of your data, preferably from `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: @ALollz yes you are right. It is actually empty string. So how do I solve it without manually parsing the dictionary.

Comment: You need to first replace the empty strings with `NaN`, `abstract.replace('', np.NaN).dropna(how='all')`. Alternatively, you could check where everything is equal to `''`, but I'm unsure if you have a `DataFrame` or series, and over what axis you would want such to be done.

Comment: @ALollz thanks this solves the issue. If you submit it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop rows containing empty cells from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/drop-rows-containing-empty-cells-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `inplace` argument by setting it to `True` or assigning this function's result to your dataframe.

```
# Solution 1: inplace = True:

abstract.dropna(how='all', inplace = True) 
# do operation inplace your dataframe and return None.

# Solution 2: assign the function result to your own dataframe:

abstract = abstract.dropna(how='all') 
# don't do operation inplace and return a dataframe as a result. 
# Hence this result must be assigned to your dataframe
```

Note: `inplace` default value is `False`.