# remove string from dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is my dataFrame:

```
    Ordered  Items       ord_datetime   Delivered At1        Delivered
13   39      2018-01-25    14:11:06    "25-01-2018 16:40 pm"    None
14   20      2018-01-25    10:53:41    "25-01-2018 14:26 pm"    None
15   13      2018-01-22    19:53:26    "22-01-2018 21:09 pm"    None
16   11      2018-01-22    17:41:20                       ""    None
```

i want delete that empty string , i used many syntax but i don't know , i can't do this

Output:after applying `df.head().to_dict()`

```
 {13: ' "25-01-2018 16:40 pm"',
 14: ' "25-01-2018 14:26 pm"',
 15: ' "22-01-2018 21:09 pm"',
 16: ' ""',
 17: ' "21-01-2018 21:56 pm"'}
```

things i tried

- 1. try to find empty string using this `((df1.values == "").sum())` but it returns `0`
- 2. then replace `""` with `NaN` but it replace all the value  `NAN`

desire output:

```
13     "25-01-2018 16:40 pm"
14     "25-01-2018 14:26 pm"
15     "22-01-2018 21:09 pm"
17     "21-01-2018 21:56 pm"
```

Comment: Do your actual column have quotes? `""` it's hard to tell, because pandas columns don't usually show them.

Comment: What does `(df1.values == '""').sum()` return? **Edit** or how about: `(df1.values == "''''").sum()` (cut and paste to try because they *are* different)

Comment: @pault it returns `0` , i tried it

Comment: @cs95  it my data , that rows contains `""` this kind of entry

Comment: Does `df[df['col'].astype(bool)]` work?

Comment: @ALollz  it returns the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
`

Comment: @cs95  it returns `TRUE`  for all the rows

Comment: @pault second syntax is also return "Zero"

Comment: How about `df1.values.str.endswith('""').sum()`? Maybe there are also some spaces in there. It's impossible to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: This was exactly the point of my first comment, no one is able to figure out what your data actually looks like now. Please [edit] your question to add  the output of `df.head().to_dict()` so we can see what it actually looks like (rather than guess from a flimsy reconstruction of the Series repr).

Comment: @pault  non of this working :( , see i updated question , what it returns after replacing operation

Comment: @cs95 check it , i added it

Comment: OK, try `df = df[df['col'].str.replace('"', '').str.strip().astype(bool)]`

Comment: @cs95 Thanks Man , done it  , this is not a duplicate question... write this into a ANS section

Comment: It is more or less a duplicate except with the additional complication of those double quotes which should not be there. I have posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56708633/4909087).

Comment: @cs95 ok , next i will take care of it