# Drop Rows if value of subset is [] from dtype Object

Tags: pandas

my DataFrame looks like that:

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20UDb.png)

I found this but it didn´t work for me. 
[Drop rows containing empty cells from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/drop-rows-containing-empty-cells-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

i tried

```
df_model['Zustand'].replace("[]", np.nan, inplace=True)

df_model.dropna(subset=['Zustand'], inplace=True)
```

"[]" is dtype Object. I am not sure how to deal with it.

Greets
Daniele

Comment: Does my answer help? Happy to assist further

Answer (score 0):

If the column contains 'list' objects:

```
df_model['Zustand'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if len(x)==0 else x)
df_model.dropna(subset=['Zustand'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me use own data now that you didnt give me some

```
df_model=pd.DataFrame({'BildName':['D850', 'D876', 'D839','ETC'], 'Zustand':['Beto','kelo','[]','[]']})
```

Try

```
df_model['Zustand']=df_model['Zustand'].str.replace("\[\]", "")
df_model['Zustand'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df_model.dropna(subset=['Zustand'], inplace=True)
```

or
apply mask

```
m=df_model.Zustand.str.contains('\[\]')
```

Change as you wanted

```
df_model.loc[m,'Zustand']=np.nan
df_model.dropna(inplace=True)
```