# Delete rows from pandas dataframe if all its columns have empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows

```
    Name Age
0    Tom  20
1   nick  21
2           
3  krish  19
4   jack  18
5           
6   jill  26
7   nick
```

Desired output is

```
    Name Age
0    Tom  20
1   nick  21
3  krish  19
4   jack  18
6   jill  26
7   nick
```

The index should not be changed and if possible would be nice if I don't have to convert empty strings to NaN. It should be removed only if all the columns have `''` empty strings

Comment: are they empty or NaN ?

Comment: Empty string `''`. Not NaN

Comment: Related: [Drop rows containing empty cells from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29314033/7109869)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do:

```
# df.eq('') compare every cell of `df` to `''`
# .all(1) or .all(axis=1) checks if all cells on rows are True
# ~ is negate operator.
mask = ~df.eq('').all(1)

# equivalently, `ne` for `not equal`, 
# mask = df.ne('').any(axis=1)

# mask is a boolean series of same length with `df`
# this is called boolean indexing, similar to numpy's
# which chooses only rows corresponding to `True`
df = df[mask]
```

Or in one line:

```
df = df[~df.eq('').all(1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. If possible can you explain this?

Comment: @Arteezy see added comments.

Answer (score 3):

If they are `NaN` we can do `dropna` or we `replace` the empty to `NaN`

```
df.mask(df.eq('')).dropna(thresh=1)
Out[151]: 
    Name  Age
0    Tom   20
1   nick   21
3  krish   19
4   jack   18
6   jill   26
7   nick  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Empty strings are actually interpreted as `False`, so removing rows with only empty strings is as easy as keeping rows in which at least one field is not empty (i.e. interpreted as `True`) :

```
df[df.any(axis=1)]
```

or shortly

```
df[df.any(1)]
```