# Python converting index to datetime and ValueError: ('String does not contain a date:', ' ')

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I converted a column to index and now I tried to convert it into a date time index. But got the error.

My code:

```
df.set_index('Time',inplace=True) % This worked perfectly

df.index = 
ndex(['5/7/2020 7:01', '5/7/2020 7:02', '5/7/2020 7:03', '5/7/2020 7:04',
       '5/7/2020 7:05', '5/7/2020 7:06', '5/7/2020 7:07', '5/7/2020 7:08',
       '5/7/2020 7:09', '5/7/2020 7:10',
       ...
       ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
      dtype='object', name='Time', length=1441)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Present output:

```
ValueError: ('String does not contain a date:', ' ')
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you have many `' '` values in the index, how do you deal with those?

Comment: Tried to convert column 'Time' to datetime first? Maybe you need to specify a format - or set errors = 'coerce'

Comment: @CeliusStingher I placed a screen shot. I agree with you that i have `' ''. In the dataframe, I see empty rows with only index. Looks like they are causing error. How to omit them

Comment: Maybe you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/drop-rows-containing-empty-cells-from-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit the values that can't be turned into DateTime objects, you can use the argument `errors='coerce'` in your function, this will return `NaT` for the values which would have raised an error. Furthermore you should add the format or, use `infer_datetime_format=True`, this might also save some issues. All in all, you should try:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,infer_datetime_format=True,errors='coerce')
```