# Assigning a value to a column based on a mapping defined in a dictionary

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tagging

I am trying to implement a code that reads a csv file, creates a data frame out of it, and then tags each row the name of the key, if one of the columns in that row contains the same string as in the key of the dataframe.

As an example, I have the following dictionary defined:

```
Sdiction={
        "Mgage" : ["ABC Gage","XYZ Gage"],
        "Rate" : ["deg/min","rad/s","rpm"]}
```

And I have the following dataframe:

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | ABC Gage |  |
| 2 | 45 | deg/min |  |
| 3 | 150 | Gage |  |

I want to tag Col D for each row as

Row 1 - Col D = Mgage (since ABC Gage exists in the key Mgage)

Row 2 - Col D = Rate (Since deg/min exists in the key Rate)

Row 3 - Col D = Mgage (since the string Gage exists in the key Mgage, albeit partially)

Expected output:

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | ABC Gage | Mgage |
| 2 | 45 | deg/min | Rate |
| 3 | 150 | Gage | Mgage |

I am trying to figure out how to implement this part, have not yet implemented it, and therefore need help.

Comment: Can you please provide the code to instanciate the DataFrame and the matching expected output?

Comment: if by **albeit partially**, you mean as a word, then you can split the values, build an inverse dictionary, and map.

Comment: Have you tested the solution below?

Comment: I am having issues with the third command. Have been trying to resolve the errors it reports. 
I get this error:  
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'assign'`
I tried to convert the Series tmp to a frame by adding this after tmp creation:
`tmp=tmp.to_frame().reset_index()`

It gives me this error:
`pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: Which pandas version did you use? Can you try the latest?

Comment: I was using pandas 1.3.3. Upgrading it now to 2.1.1 and will try again

Comment: It still gives me the same error: 
`pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: Does it produce the error with the above example? If not please provide a reproducible example that triggers the error.

Comment: It does work now. I was trying to adapt this code into my code, but when I try it as it is, it works. Thanks.

I do see an issue now if I try to expand the dataframe df, it does not classify correctly.

Comment: If my data is defined as such:
`data = {
"Col B": [30, 45, 150,25,35,65],
"Col C": ["ABC Gage", "deg/min", "Gage","rad/s 125","XYZ","rpm 458"]
}`

I get NaN for row 3, 4 and 6

Comment: I had some empty cells in my actual Col C data, which was creating problems and giving the error above:
`pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Followed this to fix that problem:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/drop-rows-containing-empty-cells-from-a-pandas-dataframe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regex match:

```
import re

s = df['Col C'].str.casefold()
pattern = '(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, s))
# '(abc\\ gage|deg/min|gage)'

# reverse dictionary
tmp = pd.Series({v.casefold(): k for k, l in Sdiction.items()
                 for v in l}, name='ref').reset_index()

# extract first match, map reference key
df['Col D'] = s.map(tmp.assign(match=tmp['index'].str.extract(pattern))
                       .dropna(subset=['match'])
                       .set_index('match')['ref']
                    )
```

Output:

```
   Col A  Col B     Col C  Col D
0      1     30  ABC Gage  Mgage
1      2     45   deg/min   Rate
2      3    150      Gage  Mgage
```

Answer (score 0):

NumPy's vectorized operations like np.isin and str.lower are optimized for efficient handling of large arrays, leading to faster execution.

This method consumes slightly more memory due to the creation of the lookup table, but this is usually offset by the faster execution speeds.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict = {
    "Mgage": ["ABC Gage", "XYZ Gage"],
    "Rate": ["deg/min", "rad/s", "rpm"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Col A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "Col B": [30, 45, 150, 70, 60],
    "Col C": ["ABC Gage", "deg/min", "Gage", "rad/s", "rpm"]
})

lookup_table = {v.lower() : k for k,l in dict.items() for v in l }
"""print(lookup_table)
{'abc gage': 'Mgage', 'xyz gage': 'Mgage', 'deg/min': 'Rate', 'rad/s': 'Rate', 'rpm': 'Rate'}
"""
df['Col_C_lower'] = df['Col C'].str.lower()

# Vectorized matching using NumPy
matches  = np.isin(df['Col_C_lower'].to_numpy(),list(lookup_table.keys()))
"""print(matches)
[ True  True False  True  True]"""

# Map matches to dictionary keys using the lookup table
df['Col_Matches'] = df['Col_C_lower'].map(lookup_table).where(matches, df['Col C'])

# Drop the temporary column, optional
#df.drop('Col_C_lower', axis=1, inplace=True)
"""print(df)
   Col A  Col B     Col C Col_C_lower   Col_Matches
0      1     30  ABC Gage    abc gage       Mgage
1      2     45   deg/min     deg/min        Rate
2      3    150      Gage        gage        Gage
3      4     70     rad/s       rad/s        Rate
4      5     60       rpm         rpm        Rate"""
```