# How to drop data using dropna()

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop the missing value in the data frame, my original data was a '-' so I have set
'-' as na value. I have tried with dropna() but the output was the name of the column in the excel file. Can someone advise where I have done wrongly?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("1.xlsx",index_col='Variables',na_values=['-'])
print("First 10 rows")
df1 = df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
first_10_rows = df1.head(10)
print(first_10_rows)
print(" ")
print("after dropping with missing data")
df2 = first_10_rows.dropna()
print(df2)
```

Sample data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRo11.png)

Comment: Pls post a sample of your data

Comment: hi, i have included the sample data.

Comment: You want to remove columns 1 & 2?

Comment: I want to remove columns with NaN data which are columns 1 & 2 in this data.

Comment: Then see my answer below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop rows containing empty cells from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/drop-rows-containing-empty-cells-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

I have to make many assumptions to answer your question.

Let's assume that column names are '1', '2', '3', '4'.

If you want to drop '2' & '3' then you need to:

```
df.drop(columns=['2', '3'], inplace =True)
```

If you want to remove all columns which contain only nulls:

```
df = df.replace('-', None) # replace '-' with Nulls
df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
```

If you want to remove rows where both '2' & '3' contain '-' then:

```
df = df.replace('-', None) # replace '-' with Nulls
df.dropna(subset=['2', '3'], inplace =True) # remove nulls
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that what you want to achieve is to drop all lines where at least one value is `NaN`; the easiest way is to use

```
df.dropna(how='any')
```

[image]

In your sample data, all rows would contain `NaN` so the resulting `DataFrame` would be empty:
[image]\

In your code:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

selects rows from `df` that contain `NaN`

and then

```
df2 = first_10_rows.dropna()
```

drops all selected rows, i.e. the result is an empty DataFrame

[image]

Comment: thanks for explaining. I have included the sample data, there are still 2 rows with no NaN, how can I made those 2 rows appear?

Comment: I have amended my code to `print("after dropping columns with missing data")
first_10_rows.dropna(how='any')
print(first_10_rows)` but the output is still showing those rows with NaN.